# Discrete Random Variables when tossing a coin

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The quesion is :
\begin{align}
   \ ~\text{ A fair coin is tosses three times and X = number of heads. The probability function of X is}    \end{align}
The answer given is:
\begin{align}
   \ p(0)= 1/8 \\ p(1)= 3/8 \\ p(2) = 3/8 \\ p(3) = 1/8
    \end{align}

I am not sure how they got this answer so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: count the ways each event can occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three tosses of a coin will result in following outomes $A = \left \{ HHH, HHT, HTH, THH, HTT, THT, TTH, TTT \right \}$

Since the number of heads in three tosses of coin can be $0,1,2$ or $3$, the sample space of $X$ is $\left \{0,1,2,3\right \}.$

$X = 0$ when one of $A_0 = \left \{TTT\right \}$ occurs.

$X = 1$ when one of $A_1 = \left \{HTT, THT, TTH\right \}$ occurs.

$X = 2$ when one of $A_2 = \left \{HHT, HTH, THH\right \}$ occurs.

$X = 3$ when one of $A_3 = \left \{HHH\right \}$ occurs.

Therefore, $P(X=1) = \frac{|A_1|}{|A|}  = \frac{3}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

Denote $n$ as the number of Head given out. There are $\displaystyle{3\choose n}$ ways to get $n$ Heads out of $3$ tosses.

The probability of getting $n$ heads is $\displaystyle(\frac12)^n$ while probability of getting $3-n$ tails as the remaining wanted outcomes of the tosses is $\displaystyle(\frac12)^{3-n}$. So $\displaystyle P(X=n)={3\choose n} \cdot(\frac12)^n(\frac12)^{3-n}=\frac18{3\choose n}$.

Comment: yes but how would you get p(1) = 3/8

Comment: Do you know what is the value of $3\choose 1$?

Answer (score 0):

0 heads: TTT, so prob. is 1/8

1 heads: HTT,THT, TTH, so prob. is 3/8

2 heads: HHT, HTH, THH, so prob. is 3/8

3 heads: HHH, prob. is 1/8

There are total 8 possibilities, that's why we divided by 8.